# Sorting a dataframe that has list in it

Tags: r, shiny

I have a below dataframe where the column types are list.

```
new_df <- structure(list(ID = list(ID = "21", ID = "4"), 
               MET = structure(list(c("A", "B"), c("C", "D")), .Names = c("","")), 
               REGN = structure(list(c("ALL", "US"), "ALL"), .Names = c("", "")), 
               YEAR = list(YEAR = "2020", YEAR = "2020"), 
               WEEK = list(WEEK = c("12", "13", "14"), WEEK = "16"), 
               ANN = list(ANN = "Seller",ANN = "Rise")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

But the issue is , I am not able to sort it. If it try to sort i get below error

```
Error in rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep") : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'greater'
```

Comment: You want to sort it but which column(s) ?

Comment: Say ID. In fact any column. If I put this DT table shiny also,  I am not able to sort since it is a list

Comment: The type is list because you set it yourself or you do not have control over that ? Being honest it's kind of annoying to work with list inside of a dataframe

Comment: I find list-columns to be much more elegant than alternatives in certain situations, but many tools for ordering/analyzing/summarizing/... are all premised on each column being a vector. This is likely true of most R frame utilities, but most notably `sort`, `order`, and `rank` all need vectors as input.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that `DT` is going to have a way to sort `list`s, but I think you need to calculate order a bit more verbosely:

```r
new_df[order(sapply(new_df$WEEK,  function(z) max(as.integer(z)))),]
#   ID  MET    REGN YEAR       WEEK    ANN
# 1 21 A, B ALL, US 2020 12, 13, 14 Seller
# 2  4 C, D     ALL 2020         16   Rise
```

The key is passing vectors to `order`. One can add multi-column ordering (tie-breakers) as well, with additional `sapply` calls:

```r
new_df[order(
  -sapply(new_df$WEEK,  function(z) max(as.integer(z))),
   sapply(new_df$MET, `[`, 1)
),]
```

Note that each of the `sapply`s can return a character or a number, but in order to do per-column *decreasing* sorts by prepending a negative (as in my examples above), it must be some form of numeric.